# How to get user permission from a database in Yii

Tags: yii, access-rules

I am very very new to Yii. I am developing a real world example.
I have a table,hence a model, called user which gets the data from database. Three main fields in Database are username,password and userRole.
Username and password work just fine.
All I need to look at the userRole in database and based on that, assign a role to a user.
For example is the user's userRole field ==1, the user is admin and can Create, Read,Update and Delete (CRUD).
But if user's userRole ==2, user can Update and Create but not delete.
I tried to do it with 'expression' ib  accessRules() in UserController.php but it didnt work.
Then I read about it and found I should do it with role.
That's what I wrote:

```
public function accessRules()
    {
        $auth = Yii::app()->authManager;

        $auth->createOperation('createUser','create a user');
        $auth->createOperation('updateUser','update a user');
        $auth->createOperation('deleteUser','delete a user');

        $role=$auth->createRole('creator');
        $role->addChild('createUser');

        $role=$auth->createRole('updater');
        $role->addChild('updateUser');

        $role=$auth->createRole('deleter');
        $role->addChild('deleteUser');


        return array(
................................
        array('allow',
            'actions'=>array('create','update'),
            'users'=>array('@'),
            'roles'=>????,

.....................
```

??? is where I have no idea what to do.
Am I defining the createOperation/addChild in a right place/file?
How can I use 'roles' in the returning array?
Also where should I get the userRole from Database?

I am desperately looking for answer as Yii Forum is not active

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must assign role(s) to logged user (or by known user id)

```
$auth->assign('creator',user()->id);
$auth->assign('updater', 102); //102 as user id
//...
```

And in accessRules you must write

```
'actions'=>array('create','update'),
'roles'=>array('creator','updater'),
```

Is this answeryou are looking for?

Answer (score 0):

The creation of operations and roles is a one time activity (whenever you create or edit them). You need to have a separate method which you will call once.

And if you want to have a role based access system in place you need to add additional tables to your database. The schema can be found in the folder - yii/framework/web/auth/schema.sql.

But the easiest way to implement RBAC would be to use an extension like Rights - http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/rights/